Doing Quantum State Tomography on a custom-made gate with Qiskit Pulse
In this simple example I took the Qiskit CX gate, obtained the pulses' schedule and then tried to do Tomography on that. In theory, everything should run smoothly (I think) but I get this "error" message. Does anybody know why / a possible solution to this problem?
import qiskit
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeValencia
from qiskit.circuit import Gate
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography

from qiskit import pulse
from qiskit.pulse import Play, drive_channel, control_channels
from qiskit.pulse.library import GaussianSquare

backend = FakeValencia()

control_qubit = 0 
target_qubit = 1 

# Get the backend defaults which include instruction schedules
backend_defaults = backend.defaults()
inst_sched_map = backend_defaults.instruction_schedule_map

# I want to know the pulse schedule for a CNOT gate
cx_schedule = inst_sched_map.get('cx', (control_qubit, target_qubit))

# Draw the pulse schedule
cx_schedule.draw(backend=backend)

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

cr_gate = Gate('cr_gate', num_qubits=2, params=[]) # Here we prepare a custom made circuit that does not do anything.

qc.append(cr_gate, [control_qubit, target_qubit])

qc.add_calibration( 'cr_gate', [0,1], cx_schedule ) # Here I added the pulse schedule to characterized the custom gate.

qc.draw()

qst_exp = StateTomography(qc) 
qst_data = qst_exp.run(backend=backend).block_for_results()

Here's the error message:
Adding a job from a backend (AerSimulator('aer_simulator'
             noise_model=<NoiseModel on ['sx', 'measure', 'x', 'id', 'cx']>)) that is different than the current backend (fake_valencia). The new backend will be used, but service is not changed if one already exists.
jobs and analysis raised exceptions [Experiment ID: 22a13973-b7cd-4fac-9f4c-a011c99651a0]:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cwd/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qiskit_experiments/framework/experiment_data.py", line 852, in _add_job_data
    job_result = job.result()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cwd/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qiskit_aer/jobs/utils.py", line 42, in _wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cwd/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qiskit_aer/jobs/aerjob.py", line 114, in result
    return self._future.result(timeout=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cwd/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cwd/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/cwd/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
...
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'AerJob' object has no attribute 'error_message'"

